# How to set up a field group on keywords in bibdesk? (not found in documentation of bibdesk)

Tags: bibdesk

I accidentally deleted the group that displays various keywords in bibdesk.

It should look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS1d4.jpg

I found this documentation entry that explains field groups: https://bibdesk.sourceforge.io/manual/BibDeskHelp_33.html

So: How can I set up this group by keywords manually?

I have reinstalled bibdesk, but the issue remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the menu bar, select: **View → Group Fields → Keywords**. Then the Keywords field group will appear in the groups sidebar. Notice that **Keywords** is now checked in the Group Fields menu that you just accessed.

You can add more field groups for different fields to the groups sidebar by selecting more field names from the Group Fields menu or by using the command **Add Group Field…** at the bottom of that menu.

The Group Fields menu also pops up as a contextual menu if you right-click or control-click on any field group title (e.g. "Keywords") in the groups sidebar.